# вылетает ошибка приложения(0xc000007b) при попытке запустить приложение на Delphi5

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

Есть цель присоединить dll, написанную на c++(MVS), к приложению на Delphi5. На Windows 7(x86) все получалось. При попытке создания dll на Windows 10(x64) при запуске приложения вылетает диалоговое окно с ошибкой приложения 0xc000007b.
При использование утилиты Dependency Walker наблюдается следующая картина:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В dependency walker есть возможность запустить приложение (F5). Запустите и он даст более подробный лог что именно не найдено.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `0xc000007b` часто обусловлена тем, что существуют библиотеки dll с одним и тем же именем, но разной разрядности - 32 и 64, а используется программой неправильная версия.

Сама dll-ка должна быть той же разрядности, что и программа, т.е. 32-х разрядной.
В среде Visual Studio это перед компиляцией переключается в выпадающем списке Solution Platform (справа от Debug/Release) - должно быть x86.

Кроме того, библиотека нужной разрядности, если к ней не указан абсолютный путь, должна лежать рядом с программой или по стандартному пути - например, в `Window\SysWOW64` (для 32-х разрядной версии)